# static and final static assignment

Tags: java, variables, static, variable-assignment, final

I was using same kind of concept , I used in first class.
b was initialized to 0 and I got 0 everywhere I used b.
After some time I got the reason and ran debugger and saw a has not been allocated any value till function call.variable a has only value default value 0.

but when I ran class Test2. It gave output 5.

I wanna know when this initialization occured?
I know that static variables get value at compilation time. But what about static final?
when this variable got it's value?

```
public class Test1 {

    static int b=add();
    static int add()
    {
        return a;
    }
    static int a=5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
//Gives output 0


public class Test2 {

    static int b=add();
    static int add()
    {
        return a;
    }
    final static int a=5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}

//gives output 5
```

Comment: `a` has not been assigned  in *Test 1* if you move the `static int a=5;` to line one you will get 5. As you have declared `a` as final in *Test 2* the value will have been set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `final static` fields of primitive and `String` types are handled specially by java compiler: they are compile time constants. Their value is just inlined into the code where it used. Let's take a look on generated bytecode.

`Test1` class:

```
static int add();
Code:
   0: getstatic     #17                 // Field a:I
   3: ireturn
```

So it really loads a static field.

`Test2` class:

```
static int add();
Code:
   0: iconst_5
   1: ireturn
```

Here it just pushes a predefined constant value `5` without even referencing the constant field.

Answer (score 4):

From section [12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) of the Java Language Specifications , The procedure for initializing Class is as follows:

> - Then, initialize the final class variables and fields of interfaces    whose values are compile-time constant expressions (§8.3.2.1, §9.3.1, 
>     §13.4.9, §15.28).
> - Next, execute either the class variable    initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field    initializers of the
>     interface, in textual order, as though they were    a single block.

So final variables will be initialized before the static variables. and you will get output `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to other answers:

In your first case where `a` is not final, `b`'s value is assigned before `a`, which is why you get 0. The sequence of assignment is determined by the sequence of statements. If you move `static int a=5;` before `b`'s assignment statement you will get 5.